# How to get data in JSON from a API with jQuery? Without errors, like: cross domains, transferred with MIME type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

### Here dont working =(

A searching here of hours and hours and nothing. =(

the url API is: http://www.poatransporte.com.br/php/facades/process.php?a=nc&p=2821&t=o

It' return a json. 
I try jsonp with jquery ajax and getJSON, but nothing. Somewhere the error is the data returned in MIME type, others the limited CORS. The interesting is: the response its ok (Google tools), but the console.log shows the errors mentioned above.

Some ninja could take the data from above url with jquery, and make some data appear in some div or give a alert()?

### Now working!

With jQuery dont work because security etc... But in server side work fine. In PHP I use this:

`<?php 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.poatransporte.com.br/php/facades/process.php?a=nc&p=2821&t=o'));
print_r($data);
 ?>`

Comment: Could you show us the code that is giving you an error please?

Comment: @thatidiotguy Shure, this is code with getJSON:
`$.getJSON('http://www.poatransporte.com.br/php/facades/process.php?a=nc&p=2821&t=o&callback=?', function(response) {
      console.log(response);   
  });`

Comment: That API doesn't support JSONP. You need to write a local proxy to get around the same-origin policy.

Comment: It looks to me like the API is working as intended. You are going to have to make those calls to the API server-side to avoid breaking same-origin policy.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, thank you! I doubt it. How you know this? Whit firebug or chrome developers?

Comment: Put the URL with `&callback=foo` into the browser address bar. The displayed page was ordinary JSON, not JSONP.